# About integral of composition of functions

Tags: real-analysis

In my notes I have $\int f\circ T d\mu = \int fd\mu T^{-1}$ where say $T:\mathcal{C}[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which I don't understand ($\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ and $T$ is bounded and continuous)? $\mu$ is the Weiner measure. I know it probably happens because of change of variables and is probably too simple but can someone explain why?

For a Lebesgue $\int f(g(x))dx$, if I do $g(x)=w$, then assuming $g$ is one-one

$$x = g^{-1}(w)\implies dx = (g^{-1})'(w)dw\implies \int f(g(x))dx = \int f(w)dw(g^{-1})'(w)$$

so I am missing a derivative in the original statement but am not sure. Appreciate an explanation.

Comment: The derivative is hidden in $d\mu T^{-1}$ (this notation is really not the best): it is the Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Comment: Please define all objects. What are $\mathcal{R}$, $\mu$? Which properties do we assume for $T$? Which is the framework for the question? If we are inside stochastics (probability theory, measure theory) note that there is a "transport formula" (which is not exactly a change of variables). Specifically, if $T:(A,\mathcal A)\to (B,\mathcal B)$ is a measurable map between measurable spaces (with $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal A,\mathcal B$ on them), then we have a preimage map $T^{-1}$ from $\mathcal B$ to $\mathcal A$. If the last carries some $\mu$ there is a $\mu\circ T^{-1}$, transported meas..

Comment: @dan_fulea Thanks, made edits now.